# Python showing error - name 'Object' is not defined

Tags: python

Python interpreter is showing NameError on using Object.

```
>>> class test(Object): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Object' is not defined
```

Python version is 2.7.3.

I haven't been able to remove this error. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`object`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) must be lower-case. Try

```
>>> class test(object): pass
```

In Python 3.x, you can also just leave it out:

```
>>> class test: pass
```

(In 2.x, you should not do that until you are ready to face the monstrosity of [classic classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes))

Answer (score -1):

yes，it is need to lower-case:

```
#define class

class Student(object):

print('start')

# name & score

def _init_(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def printScore(self):
        print('%s: %s' % (self.name, self.score))

    def set_score(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError('score must be an Integer')
        if value < 0 or value > 100:
            raise ValueError('score must between 0 ~ 100!')

        self.score = value

    def get_score(self):
        return self.score
```